# No desktop after login?

Tags: xorg, lightdm, ubuntu-minimal

So I just installed Ubuntu Minimal 64bit and when I login it just leaves me on what looks like a command page that says `jerric@Jerric-HP:~$`. I don't have Windows anymore, I think. What do I do?

Edit: Don't bother, anymore. I'm just going to reset my computer back to Windows. Thanks for trying guys :)  Ill leave this up incase it helps anyone else.

Comment: try pressing ctrl+alt+F7 and see what happens

Comment: Is the "s" actually a dollar sign?  What exact ISO or install file did you install Ubuntu from?

Comment: Ctrl +alt+f7 cleared everything

Comment: My bad, the s is a dollar sign. I installed the minimal 64 bit Iso

Comment: I've noticed that I'm not connected to the Internet either, is there a way I can do that while being stuck here I'm the login screen?

Comment: Minimal ISO - version without desktop by default.

Comment: how do you know you are not connected to the internet?

Answer (score -1):

Since you're using WPA you'll need to do this:

`wpa_passphrase ESSID > wpa.conf`  replace ESSID with that of your router

You'll then type in your passphrase and it'll generate a file similar to this wpa.conf in your current working directory:

```
network={
    ssid="myrouter"
    #psk="mypassphrase"
    psk=8ada1f8dbea59704ac379538b4d9191f6a72390581b4cd7a72864cea685b1a7f
}
```

next:
`sudo wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlan0 -c/root/wpa.conf -B`

remember to change `/root/wpa.conf` to your home directory

then request an IP address:
`sudo dhclient wlan0`

After that, update, and install a desktop

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop^`

then reboot, and you should be good to go

Comment: I can't do that, it wont connect to the Internet

Comment: Are you trying to use wifi or ethernet?

Comment: I'm trying to use WiFi

Comment: check my edit, and see if that helps

Comment: Alright, it says "Operation not possible due to RF-kill" after I type "sudo dhclient wlan0"

Comment: look again, I changed it

Comment: Alright, there is a password to connect to the WiFi if that helps you

Comment: is it WEP or WPA? also it really would be a lot easier for you just to plug into the router. You can set wireless up later after you get a GUI

Comment: It's WPA. Unfortunately, I can't plug into the router. Sorry, this is so complicated

Comment: then you'll need to use `wpa_supplicant` type `wpa_supplicant --help` to see if you have it already, if not, I don't know how to help you other than start over with a full distro

Comment: ok, check my new edit and try that out

Comment: Dammit it was working fine and then I got "Failed to open config file '/root/wpa.conf', error: no such file or directory“. By the way, thanks so much for trying to help me out, I know helping a noob is frustrating

Comment: Sorry you'll need to change that to your home directory. Try using ~/wpa.conf

Comment: Permission denied

Comment: try `sudo wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlan0 -c/home/jeric/wpa.conf -B`

Comment: I get "rfkill: Well hard blocked" so whatever RFkill is, is messing everything up, I'm guessing

Comment: Make sure your WiFi card is turned on and try `rfkill unblock all`

Comment: It doesn't turn on, I know it works but it shuts off when I boot Ubuntu. I tried that and it said that rfkill isn't installed. I think at this point, I'm pretty much screwed

Comment: You need to just plug into the router or get a full distribution

Comment: @user309798 that's most likely referring to the wifi fn key on your laptop you need to switch that on by pressing the wifi button (possibly in combination with the fn key)

Comment: Hi! Can I clean these comments up now? All important information should be edited into the relevant question/answer. Thanks!